# React Inline styling on state change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an input whose width I want to change on state change. I want it to inherit all properties but just change the width property. I've tried a couple of things and nothing is working. So my styles are like this

```
  input: { 
    width: "40vw",
    color: "gray",
    padding: 10,
    height: 30,
  }
```

and I'm checking for state and trying to use this

```
 let inputClass = classes.input
    if(navShow) {
      inputClass = classes.input.width === '100vw'
    }
```

and applying it like

```
<input className = {inputClass}
```

I want the input to inherit all the other properties. I don't want to have to rewrite all those styles in another object. How can I do this?

Comment: codepen or jsfiddle link please ?

Comment: Why aren't you just modifying the `width` property of the `inputClass` if `navShow` is true?

Comment: @Katie.Sun I'm not understanding what you mean by that.

Comment: in this line: `inputClass = classes.input.width === '100vw'`, you are reassigning `inputClass` to true or false, depending on how `classes.input.width === '100vw'` is evaluated. you should just be changing `inputClass.width` to `'100vw'` if I understand your question

Comment: @Katie.Sun Thanks Katie, that works!

Comment: @AnneJoday cool! :)

Answer (score 1):

On this line: `inputClass = classes.input.width === '100vw'` you are reassigning `inputClass` to be a `boolean`. Instead, you should just modify the value of `inputClass`'s `width` property, like so:

```
let inputClass = classes.input
    if(navShow) {
      inputClass.width = '100vw'
    }
return (
  <input style={inputClass} />
);
```

**EDIT:** You should change your JSX to use `style` instead of `className` because you are passing in a style object and not a css class. Hopefully this fixes the other problem.

Comment: Im getting an error with this now. it says " Cannot create property 'width' on string"

Comment: do `console.log(inputClass)` on the line after you declare it... It must be a string. Maybe if you can see its value you will be able to tell where `classes.input` is actually coming from

Comment: This is what I get. I'm not sure what Search-input-135 is coming from. INPUT CLASS IS:  Search-input-135

Comment: I'm not either haha. But I'm pretty sure if that's the case then your other styles (besides width) aren't being applied either, because you're not actually getting `classes.input` from where you think you are, no?

Comment: Hey Anne, I just realized, you are tying to use `className`, but you are returning an object (`className`) requires a string. I will update my answer

Comment: That won't work because I am using the autosuggest library for my search input. And that takes input prop as a string.

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates? I can't help with parts of your code I can't see

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic class by if condition inside the `className`

```
<input className = {navShow ? inputClass : anotherClass} />
```

`inputClass` witspecificic style & `anotherClass` with another style

Comment: Yeah that's fine but all the other styles that I have applied for the input I'd have to redeclare them. Too much repetitive code.

Comment: Yes you're right, I think the solution is creating states that take a values, and updates with `setState`, `if navShow { setState(new style of margin) }` something like that, you will have general style